# Labels in fields within an SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, format, label, block

I am attempting to reproduce a form within SSRS and fill it with data.  The original form has blocks with small labels inside of each box that identifies the entry requested.

[image]

I "thought" I could simply use two different tablixes: one for the blocks with borders and labels, and the other one with the actual datafields or expressions, and align the 2nd tablix directly ***over*** the first one so that it appears as though the fields are presenting data inside of the labeled boxes.

It looked as I wanted it in design view, but when I went to preview the report, it pushed the 2nd tablix below the first tablix, in effect creating two tablixes, one stacked on top of the other one (not displaying as how I intended).

[image]

So, how do I accomplish the form design in the manner that I am seeking?

Comment: Perhaps if you could post an image of a similar design that might help.

Comment: I wish I could, but it requires 10 stupid points and I only have 8 :-(

Comment: Upload the image to Imgur or similar then add a link to this in the question; another user can edit and add the image to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could reproduce that form header quite easily with a single tablix. If you envisage the form as a set of tablix cells like so:

[image]

then all you need to do is set the Border properties for each cell to hide the borders as needed (or you could merge the cells e.g those for Applicant and Location).

You can use a tablix with only Header rows, deleting the detail row. If you need multiple forms per report, then put the tablix inside a List region.

Comment: Silly me - so simple yet still not obvious to me.  Yep, that did the trick, @Nathan.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a type other than tablix for your report.  Use a 'List' instead and you can free float objects as you need them and also nest a tablix as well.  A little explanation on list:

1. You can float images with text boxes and then even change syntax or draw boxes around them and decorate those.
2. The call out for a field in SSRS is [(value)]  with the [] meaning: "Data Column in recognized Dataset"
3. You can call out Variables with an '@' in front of them [@Test] would be a variable a user would put in called 'Test'.
4. Whatever size 'List' element is will determine how large it is when it repeats.  If you want a strict form ensure the length and width are set correctly on the properties of that element.
5. If you want it to break every page you can click on the 'List' > Right Click the top left corner > Properties > 'Add a page break before' checkbox.

My example shows a super simple textbox with a dataset that only has three ideas repeat as many times as there are id's, three times.  You can apply this to your form as needed.

[image]

Comment: Edited my comment please check again.